# No such file or directory after creating a .exe file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.4, py2exe

I've made a script which will make a new post for the user in his facebook profile. It worked fine before using `py2exe` but after creating the `.exe` file it keeps giving me the same error.

Code:

```
import facebook, time

try:
    token = input("Your Token: ")
    text = input("The new post: ")
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
    fb_response = graph.put_wall_post(text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    time.sleep(50)
```

Error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Note: The `.pyc` (Python compiled file) is working fine without any errors. Only the `.exe` file is giving the error.

Comment: Does this only happen with this python program or also with other (maybe even more minimal) ones? Have you tried with an empty `*.py` file?

Comment: Also, is the `import` line really indented or is that something that happened when posting the code?

Comment: I've already made some other scripts using py2exe (A calculator, 'XO' game) also i've used GUI in these scripts and they are working fine. But this one just gave me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I've just used `PyInstaller` and it work fine. Thanks any way